# Display image Alt Attribute text on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to know how to display `alt` text of `img`, inside of `p` element on mouse hover.

Here's my **HTML:**

```
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="one"/>
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="two"/>
<img src="img3.jpg" alt="three"/>

<p id="text"> </p>
```

And **JS:**

```
function showAlt(){
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  for(var i=0; i < img.length; i++){
    img[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
      var alt = img[i].alt;
      alt.appendChild(text);}}

}
```

And JSfiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ywLjkgah/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change text of `p` element with `textContent` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ywLjkgah/1/)

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var text = document.getElementById("text");

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var alt = this.alt;
    text.textContent = alt;
  });
}
```

If you want to remove text on `mouseleave` you can add another event and change text to empty string [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ywLjkgah/2/)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of the context for this, but the title="" attribute is often shown as a tooltip for images. Should work in all of the desktop browsers, so I'm not sure if you need JS to do this.

Comment: That's not what he's asking. He wants to display the `alt` text in another HTML element when hovered on.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that his setup is slightly different. Just giving an alternative if they weren't already aware. The title was more general so it might have been a helpful alternative.